# Filter Columns of Gridview by Dropdownlist (not inside Gridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple dropdownlist with let's say 3 entries: "WLTP", "NEDC", "RDE" outside of a gridview.

Then I have a normal gridview with these column-names:
"ID", "Name", "WLTP", "NEDC", "RDE".

I get the data through ADO.net from an Access database.

Now, what I simply want is that the user clicks on the dropdownlist and selects one entry, e.g. "NEDC".

Now, the colums "ID", "Name" should always be displayed, but only the column "NEDC" should be displayed, not the remaining "WLTP" and "RDE".

My question:
Do I have to modify my SELECT QUERY in code which was originally:

```
SELECT ID, Name, WLTP, NEDC, RDE FROM tblName;
```

to the reduced version:

```
SELECT ID, Name, NEDC FROM tblName;
```

But this is not efficient to do another database connect right?

Can I simply filter the gridview itself?

Regards!

Comment: hide the unwanted column based on the dropdown selection

Comment: paging / sorting enabled on the grid?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to change the sql query and hit the database each time. Instead you can use the `DropdownList_SelectedIndexChagned` Event of the list and in that event you can set the gridview columns visibility.[Here is more info on the event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[Here is one tutorial explains how to do it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43727/Show-Hide-GridView-Columns-in-ASP-NET).

Comment: this will break if the gridview have sorting and/or paging enabled

Comment: I have hided the unneeded columns. That works. But not with paging unfortunately. What is good practise if you want to hide columns according to users filtering AND to keep paging? I mean what is an professional approach?